# Invalid Gas Used and Missing trie node when starting a mining geth node

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

When leaving my rig mining off for a couple days and starting geth again, sometimes I get this an "Invalid Gas Used" error and "Missing trie node". What does this mean? Any ideas on what could be causing it? I've had to redownload the chain when I get stuck.

[image: Gas Error]

Comment: Could you run a system check on your hard-disk / SSD? You could have faulty sectors.

Comment: sure, I have a couple miners that will do this every once in a while though.

Comment: @BadrBellaj that post is windows with antivirus - they are similar because both represent malformed chain data but this is on linux with no antivirus. I'll be swapping out the harddrives and trying again today.